# Align image position of button by CSS

Tags: css, image, button, alignment

I have a Button with a background-image and a text that is more than the width of the image.
How to place the image in the middle of the text

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.button {
  background: url('http://127.0.0.1/pics/item/c1763.png')  no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  padding-top:60px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-position: center center;
  display: flex;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button class="button">Button text test</button>

</body>
</html>
```

[Button image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxHaN.jpg)

Comment: try background-size:contain

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it didn't have any effect on the image alignment

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```css
.button {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxHaN.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-position: center center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Button text test</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the image still appears on the left side of button

Comment: Change your button width. Now having width:60px;

Comment: Thanks for your guidance
This is the final solution
Change the width of the button to the text width and set the image width to the actual size

Answer (score 0):

The final solution is determine the actual width of the image and to specify the width of the button for the text

```html
.button2 {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url('http://127.0.0.1:25005/pics/item/c1763.png');
  background-size: 60px  60px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 60px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  background-position: center top;
}
```